# Número de linhas aumenta após o uso do JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Olá, sou novo no SQL e estou tendo uma dúvida. Como no exemplo abaixo, queria pegar de uma tabela 'b' a descrição do código presente na tabela 'a'. Porém o número de linhas da tabela 'a' quando eu faço isso aumenta significativamente.

```
select a.banana, a.caju, b.descgenero 
from vegetais b
INNER JOIN desc b
on (a.cod = b.cod and a.est = b.est and a.colheita = b.colheita)
```

Já vi casos usando o INNER JOIN em que a tabela 'a' fica menor, caso não tenha o código correspondendo na tabela 'b', mas não entendo porque o número de linhas da tabela 'a' pode ter aumentado. Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficarei grato.

Comment: Seria bom por um [mcve] num [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) ou coisa do tipo para esclarecer melhor, e facilitar a visualização do fenômeno..

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta não esta muito clara, mas acredito que isso só pode esta acontecendo pelo fato de você ter um relacionamento 1-N, (UM PARA MUITOS) entre suas tabelas *vegetais* ou *desc*.

Por exemplo.

Suponha que sua tabela **vegetais**  tenha o `cod = 1 est = 1 colheita = 1` e sua tabela **desc** tenha os mesmos `cod = 1 est = 1 colheita = 1` mas duas vezes e não uma só quando você fizer o select abaixo ele ira retorna duas linhas uma para cada relacionamento.

```
select a.banana, a.caju, b.descgenero 
from vegetais a
INNER JOIN desc b
on (a.cod = b.cod and a.est = b.est and a.colheita = b.colheita)
```